# Finding the beat rate of a song

Tags: sound

I'm trying to use Mathematica to find out the beat rate of a song.

The image below shows some markups I made in another program in milliseconds.

[image]

I was able to find that there is a pattern every second.

In others words [120 BPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo)

Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried the Periodogram, but it was not enough:

```
Periodogram[Import["C:\\Users\\LMC\\Desktop\\Teste.wav"]]
```

[image]

This is the [sound](https://www.zapsplat.com/sound-effect-category/electronica/) I analyzed.